# How to compare sublists in List[List[Double]]

Tags: list, scala

I have a `List[List[Double]]`

Ignoring the last element of each list with in outer list, I want to compare inner lists i.e. we have a

```scala
List(
  List(0.1,0.5,0.3,0),
  List(2.3,0.1,0.4,1),
  List(0.1,0.5,0.3,1)
)
```

I want distinct list ignoring last element i.e.

```scala
List(
  List(0.1,0.5,0.3,0),
  List(2.3,0.1,0.4,1)
)
```

Here the 1st and last lists are similar ignoring the last elements.
kindly provide me some clue. As I am very new to *scala*.

Comment: How should we choose between `List(0.1,0.5,0.3,0)` and `List(0.1,0.5,0.3,1)` ? If one of them has to remain in the result set, which one, and why? In your example, it seems the first one remains and the second one gets dropped. Is this a general rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Scala `2.13`+ please see @jwvh's solution, otherwise ...

You could traverse the list via `foldLeft` to assemble a new list of inner lists by checking against a `Set` of lists with distinct `init`:

```
val list = List(List(0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.0), List(2.3, 0.1, 0.4, 1.0), List(0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 1.0))

list.foldLeft((List[List[Double]](), Set[List[Double]]())){ case ((ls, s), l) =>
  val lInit = l.init
  if (s.contains(lInit)) (ls, s) else (l :: ls, s + lInit)
}._1.reverse
// res1: List[List[Double]] = List(List(0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.0), List(2.3, 0.1, 0.4, 1.0))
```

In case order of the resulting inner lists is unimportant, an alternative is to group the list by the inner list's `init`, followed by extracting the first inner list from the grouped Map `values`:

```
list.groupBy(_.init).map(_._2.head) 
// res2: List[List[Double]] = List(List(2.3, 0.1, 0.4, 1.0), List(0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.0))
```

Comment: Thanks for guidance. I think I got a clear approach.

Comment: @AqsaZahoor don’t forget to accept and upvote helpful answers. It’s a good way to say thank you and letting others know what worked for you.

Answer (score 7):

Study the Standard Library. It's amazing the things you can find there.

```
List(List(0.1,0.5,0.3,0),List(2.3,0.1,0.4,1),List(0.1,0.5,0.3,1)).distinctBy(_.init)
//res0: List[List[Double]] = List(List(0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.0), List(2.3, 0.1, 0.4, 1.0))
```

Comment: Ah, nice one.  Another new method on Scala 2.13+.